# как подключить переключатель

Tags: javascript

Ссылки стилизованы под кнопки, когда одна из них активна, то под ней полоска со стрелочкой (это стилизованно под класс .active). Поставил обработчик событий, но почему-то не выходит. В чем ошибка?

```
<ul class="btn-page">
            <li class="btn-items"><a class="active" href="#">pizza cartoon</a></li>
            <li class="btn-items"><a href="#">burger</a></li>
            <li class="btn-items"><a href="#">sandwich</a></li>
            <li class="btn-items"><a href="#">drinks</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
const itemsBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-items');
    itemsBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        itemsBtn.classList.toggle(".active");
    })
```

Comment: "Не выходит" --- вам не кажется, что это не достаточное описание проблемы?

Comment: Читайте как правильно вешать обработчик на несколько элементов

Comment: при нажатии не происходит переноса этой стрелки. в инспекторе пишет что  не является функциейindex.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: itemsBtn.addEventListener is not a function
    a

Comment: Дубликат...... .